# React - Survey.js... EDIT button for survey items not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

Trying to use Survey.js in my React application.
When  trying to load the Survey Editor i can load the initial interface but am facing problem trying edit the questions.
The "EDIT" and "..." buttons are not working. They fire the error shown in the image.

Already added Jquery ProvidePlugin in WebpackConfig.

```
 new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    $: 'jquery',
    jquery: 'jquery'
}),
```

Before adding the plugin alot of other button were not working. Now i am only having issue with the above mentioned buttons. Also can it be a bootstrap related problem.

[image]

```
Uncaught TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_jquery__(...).modal is not a function
at SurveyPropertyEditorShowWindow.show (bundle.js:201317)
at SurveyEditor.showQuestionEditor (bundle.js:205389)
at Array.<anonymous> (bundle.js:205275)
at Event.fire (bundle.js:224746)
at SurveyForDesigner._this.editQuestionClick (bundle.js:204387)
at HTMLButtonElement.btn.onclick (bundle.js:204485)
```

Below is my Webpack.config

```html
'use strict';

var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var CaseSensitivePathsPlugin = require('case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin');
var InterpolateHtmlPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/InterpolateHtmlPlugin');
var WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin');
var getClientEnvironment = require('./env');
var paths = require('./paths');



// Webpack uses `publicPath` to determine where the app is being served from.
// In development, we always serve from the root. This makes config easier.
var publicPath = '/';
// `publicUrl` is just like `publicPath`, but we will provide it to our app
// as %PUBLIC_URL% in `index.html` and `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` in JavaScript.
// Omit trailing slash as %PUBLIC_PATH%/xyz looks better than %PUBLIC_PATH%xyz.
var publicUrl = '';
// Get environment variables to inject into our app.
var env = getClientEnvironment(publicUrl);

// This is the development configuration.
// It is focused on developer experience and fast rebuilds.
// The production configuration is different and lives in a separate file.
module.exports = {
  // You may want 'eval' instead if you prefer to see the compiled output in DevTools.
  // See the discussion in https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/343.
  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  // These are the "entry points" to our application.
  // This means they will be the "root" imports that are included in JS bundle.
  // The first two entry points enable "hot" CSS and auto-refreshes for JS.
  entry: [
    // Include an alternative client for WebpackDevServer. A client's job is to
    // connect to WebpackDevServer by a socket and get notified about changes.
    // When you save a file, the client will either apply hot updates (in case
    // of CSS changes), or refresh the page (in case of JS changes). When you
    // make a syntax error, this client will display a syntax error overlay.
    // Note: instead of the default WebpackDevServer client, we use a custom one
    // to bring better experience for Create React App users. You can replace
    // the line below with these two lines if you prefer the stock client:
    // require.resolve('webpack-dev-server/client') + '?/',
    // require.resolve('webpack/hot/dev-server'),
    require.resolve('react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient'),
    // We ship a few polyfills by default:
    require.resolve('./polyfills'),
    // Finally, this is your app's code:
    paths.appIndexJs
    // We include the app code last so that if there is a runtime error during
    // initialization, it doesn't blow up the WebpackDevServer client, and
    // changing JS code would still trigger a refresh.
  ],
  output: {
    // Next line is not used in dev but WebpackDevServer crashes without it:
    path: paths.appBuild,
    // Add /* filename */ comments to generated require()s in the output.
    pathinfo: true,
    // This does not produce a real file. It's just the virtual path that is
    // served by WebpackDevServer in development. This is the JS bundle
    // containing code from all our entry points, and the Webpack runtime.
    filename: 'static/js/bundle.js',
    // This is the URL that app is served from. We use "/" in development.
    publicPath: publicPath
  },
  resolve: {
    // This allows you to set a fallback for where Webpack should look for modules.
    // We read `NODE_PATH` environment variable in `paths.js` and pass paths here.
    // We use `fallback` instead of `root` because we want `node_modules` to "win"
    // if there any conflicts. This matches Node resolution mechanism.
    // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/253
    fallback: paths.nodePaths,
    // These are the reasonable defaults supported by the Node ecosystem.
    // We also include JSX as a common component filename extension to support
    // some tools, although we do not recommend using it, see:
    // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/290
    extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.jsx', ''],
    alias: {
      // Support React Native Web
      // https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/08/a-glimpse-into-the-future-with-react-native-for-web/
      'react-native': 'react-native-web'
    }
  },
  
  module: {
    // First, run the linter.
    // It's important to do this before Babel processes the JS.
    preLoaders: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        loader: 'eslint',
        include: paths.appSrc,
      }
    ],
    loaders: [
      // ** ADDING/UPDATING LOADERS **
      // The "url" loader handles all assets unless explicitly excluded.
      // The `exclude` list *must* be updated with every change to loader extensions.
      // When adding a new loader, you must add its `test`
      // as a new entry in the `exclude` list for "url" loader.

      // "url" loader embeds assets smaller than specified size as data URLs to avoid requests.
      // Otherwise, it acts like the "file" loader.
      {
        exclude: [
          /\.html$/,
          // We have to write /\.(js|jsx)(\?.*)?$/ rather than just /\.(js|jsx)$/
          // because you might change the hot reloading server from the custom one
          // to Webpack's built-in webpack-dev-server/client?/, which would not
          // get properly excluded by /\.(js|jsx)$/ because of the query string.
          // Webpack 2 fixes this, but for now we include this hack.
          // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/1713
          /\.(js|jsx)(\?.*)?$/,
          /\.css$/,
          /\.json$/,
          /\.svg$/
        ],
        loader: 'url',
        query: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
        }
      },
      // Process JS with Babel.
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        include: paths.appSrc,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
          
          // This is a feature of `babel-loader` for webpack (not Babel itself).
          // It enables caching results in ./node_modules/.cache/babel-loader/
          // directory for faster rebuilds.
          cacheDirectory: true
        }
      },
      // "postcss" loader applies autoprefixer to our CSS.
      // "css" loader resolves paths in CSS and adds assets as dependencies.
      // "style" loader turns CSS into JS modules that inject <style> tags.
      // In production, we use a plugin to extract that CSS to a file, but
      // in development "style" loader enables hot editing of CSS.
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style!css?importLoaders=1!postcss'
      },
      // JSON is not enabled by default in Webpack but both Node and Browserify
      // allow it implicitly so we also enable it.
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json'
      },
      // "file" loader for svg
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        loader: 'file',
        query: {
          name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
        }
      }
      // ** STOP ** Are you adding a new loader?
      // Remember to add the new extension(s) to the "url" loader exclusion list.
    ]
  },
  
  // We use PostCSS for autoprefixing only.
  postcss: function() {
    return [
      autoprefixer({
        browsers: [
          '>1%',
          'last 4 versions',
          'Firefox ESR',
          'not ie < 9', // React doesn't support IE8 anyway
        ]
      }),
    ];
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        $: 'jquery',
        jquery: 'jquery'
    }),
    // Makes some environment variables available in index.html.
    // The public URL is available as %PUBLIC_URL% in index.html, e.g.:
    // <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    // In development, this will be an empty string.
    new InterpolateHtmlPlugin(env.raw),
    // Generates an `index.html` file with the <script> injected.
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: true,
      template: paths.appHtml,
    }),
    // Makes some environment variables available to the JS code, for example:
    // if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') { ... }. See `./env.js`.
    new webpack.DefinePlugin(env.stringified),
    // This is necessary to emit hot updates (currently CSS only):
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    // Watcher doesn't work well if you mistype casing in a path so we use
    // a plugin that prints an error when you attempt to do this.
    // See https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/240
    new CaseSensitivePathsPlugin(),
    // If you require a missing module and then `npm install` it, you still have
    // to restart the development server for Webpack to discover it. This plugin
    // makes the discovery automatic so you don't have to restart.
    // See https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/186
    new WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin(paths.appNodeModules)
  ],
  // Some libraries import Node modules but don't use them in the browser.
  // Tell Webpack to provide empty mocks for them so importing them works.
  node: {
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty'
  }
};
```

Comment: Post the HTML please.

Comment: please post full setting webpack, in `entry`  are you using bootstrap-loader?

Comment: @HuyTran I have not added the bootstrap-loader in webpack entry. And i am using bootstrap from CDN...in my index.html

Answer (score 0):

```
entry: {
    'js/vendor': 'bootstrap-loader',
    ...
},

...

plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "jquery",
        jQuery: "jquery",
        "window.jQuery": "jquery",
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin(
        "js/vendor",
        "js/vendor.bundle.js"
    )
],
```

and try to load `js/vendor.bundle.js` from index.html instead of bootstrap from cdn.It should work.

I got same problem before, but i removed jquery, i didn't need to use Jquery anymore in my React Project

Comment: Same problem. Now only the EDIT button not working. I have removed CDN and have done NPM install of both Boostrap and Jquery. 
Cant remove jquery as i am using Survey.js and they use Jquery. Infact i am not using Jquery in any other code block.

Comment: I would have to through the entire library. I will point you to git off Survey.js source and it's example the one I am trying to implement in my existing project

Comment: Will put it up tomorrow.